# Why doesn't lift change the stack order in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have this code as an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomWidget(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, bg_color, width=100, height=100, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(bg=bg_color)
        self.create_rectangle(0, 0, width, height, fill=bg_color, width=0)

class CustomWidgetFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, bg_color, title, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        # Create and add your custom widget as a child of the frame
        self.custom_widget = CustomWidget(self, bg_color)
        self.custom_widget.pack()

        # Add other widgets to the frame as needed
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=title)
        self.label.pack()

# Create the root window and add the custom widget frames to it
root = tk.Tk()
custom_widget_frame1 = CustomWidgetFrame(root, "red", "Widget1")
custom_widget_frame1.pack()

custom_widget_frame2 = CustomWidgetFrame(root, "blue", "Widget2")
custom_widget_frame2.pack()

# Bring the blue widget frame to the front of the red widget frame
custom_widget_frame2.lift(custom_widget_frame1)

# Start the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

`CustomWidget` is just a box of a certain color and dimesions.

`CustomWidgetFrame` is the container of said box with a label.

The reset of the code is straight forward tkinter and python:

1. Make a root element - `root = tk.Tk()`
2. Create the `CustomWidgetFrame`, setting the color and label name, then pack() it.
3. Do step 2 again.
4. Try to raise the blue box over the red box.

Why is `lift` not accomplishing my goal here (moving the blue box over the red box), and of course what is a practical way to accomplish this goal?

I assumed that the best way to make my custom widget stack vertically (by `pack()`ing it) was to store it in a container (that had my custom widget and labels and this that and what not), then just `pack()` the container and move it with `lift()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lift` works in the z-axis, so you'll only see the effect if the widgets overlap. In your code, `lift` is working as designed but the widgets don't overlap so you can't see the effect.

If what you really want to to move the widgets along the y axis you can specify the order by using the `before` or `after` options to the `pack` command.

```
custom_widget_frame2.pack(before=custom_widget_frame1)
```

Comment: Okay, so I know this isn't in my example, but if you could assume that self.pack() was called inside of CustomWidgetFrame, is there a way to order the widgets along the y-axis after being packed? So basically, I want to use the before=custom_widget_frame1 of the pack method after I've called it.

Comment: @Shmack: my example shows how - just call `pack` again with options that specify where it should be placed.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I read (from an unmentionable source at this moment in time) that `pack` can't be called an element more than once. So sure enough I tested it as per your answer, and it worked like a charm. Thank you for clarifying this and helping me get over this hump.

Comment: @Shmack: that source is wrong. You can call `pack` on a widget as many times as you want.